# How to use $compile in ng-repeat -ed directives?

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to dynamically add a couple of directives depending on the scope parameters. I've made it work, but not with ng-repeat. If I'll set directive's priority > 1000 (ng-repeat's priority), the data will be shown correctly, but without my additional directives. If I'll set it < 999, it will add my directives, but will execute ng-repeat separately for each value in the collection, basically duplicating all the data multiple times.

This is the way I'm doing it:

```
app.directive('testDirectiveLow', function ($compile) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        replace: false,
        terminal: true,
        priority: 999,
        scope: {
            tooltip: '<'
        },
        compile: function compile(element, attrs) {
            return {
                post: function postLink(scope, iElement, iAttrs, controller) {
                    console.log(scope.tooltip);
                    if (scope.tooltip) {
                        iElement.attr('uib-tooltip', 'Test tooltip');
                        iElement.attr('tooltip-placement', 'right');
                    }
                    iElement.removeAttr("test-directive-low");
                    $compile(iElement)(scope.$parent);
                }
            };
        }
    };
});
```

I've also made a plunker to demonstrate this issue. It shows how I'm dynamically adding tooltips depending on the "tooltip" attribute. First it shows how it works for static elements, then for directive with the high priority, then for the low one:
http://plnkr.co/edit/6D397kPjP1W2OtOeC01J?p=preview

Why is this happening and how can I deal with this issue?

Comment: trying putting it on an element inside the `ng-repeat` element

Comment: Thank you, but there are situations where you can't do that. Like creating <th> elements dynamically and put md-numeric on the ones that has numeric values.